# celery.service: Failed with result 'signal'

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, celery, systemd

I am setting up my django production project to work with celery on an ubuntu server. It works fine when i run task manually with
`celery -A project worker -l INFO`

but systemd stops every time i set it up and run. Configuration settings below.

**/etc/default/celeryd**

```
#   most people will only start one node:
CELERYD_NODES="worker1"
#   but you can also start multiple and configure settings
#   for each in CELERYD_OPTS
#CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2 worker3"
#   alternatively, you can specify the number of nodes to start:
#CELERYD_NODES=10

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="/home/steph/icecream/venv/bin/celery"
#CELERY_BIN="/virtualenvs/def/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
CELERY_APP="homestud"
# or fully qualified:
#CELERY_APP="proj.tasks:app"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/steph/icecream/hometutors/homestud/"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"
# Configure node-specific settings by appending node name to arguments:
#CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 -c 8 -c:worker2 4 -c:worker3 2 -Ofair:worker1"

# Set logging level to DEBUG
#CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="DEBUG"

# %n will be replaced with the first part of the node name.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
#   You need to create this user manually (or you can choose
#   a user/group combination that already exists (e.g., nobody).
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
# If enabled PID and log directories will be created if missing,
# and owned by the userid/group configured.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

**/etc/systemd/system/celery.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=celery
Group=celery

EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/celeryd
WorkingDirectory=/home/steph/icecream/hometutors/homestud
ExecStart=/home/steph/icecream/venv/bin/celery multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}
ExecStop=/home/steph/icecream/venv/bin/celery ${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}
ExecReload=/home/steph/icecream/venv/bin/celery ${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**when i run sudo systemctl status celery**

```
● celery.service - Celery Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/celery.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2021-04-06 12:38:51 UTC; 5min ago
    Process: 80579 ExecStart=/home/steph/icecream/venv/bin/celery multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CEL>
   Main PID: 80594 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Apr 06 12:37:15 homestud-ubuntu-server systemd[1]: Starting Celery Service...
Apr 06 12:37:16 homestud-ubuntu-server celery[80579]: celery multi v5.0.5 (singularity)
Apr 06 12:37:16 homestud-ubuntu-server celery[80579]: > Starting nodes...
Apr 06 12:37:16 homestud-ubuntu-server celery[80579]:         > worker1@homestud-ubuntu-server: OK
Apr 06 12:37:17 homestud-ubuntu-server systemd[1]: Started Celery Service.
Apr 06 12:37:21 homestud-ubuntu-server systemd[1]: celery.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Apr 06 12:38:51 homestud-ubuntu-server systemd[1]: celery.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Apr 06 12:38:51 homestud-ubuntu-server systemd[1]: celery.service: Killing process 80606 (python) with signal SIGKILL.
Apr 06 12:38:51 homestud-ubuntu-server systemd[1]: celery.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same issue, but turns out that it is because of low RAM (1 GB) at the production server. Kindly upgrade it to at least 2 GB and this issue will be resolved.